# Must references to wagtail.core be deleted from migration files?

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Wagtail 4.2.4 to Wagtail 5.0, and Wagtail seems to insisting that I delete all references to wagtail.core from my migration files going back to the beginning of the project three years ago. I can't understand why this would be necessary. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It's necessary because migration files are Python code like any other files in your project, and contain imports referring to the `wagtail.core` module which no longer exists as of Wagtail 5.0.

There's no need to update these imports manually, as Wagtail provides [a command to apply the changes to your codebase automatically](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/3.0.html#changes-to-module-paths):

```bash
# list the files to be changed without updating them
wagtail updatemodulepaths --list

# show the changes to be made, without updating files
wagtail updatemodulepaths --diff  

# actually update the files
wagtail updatemodulepaths
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, and I've now successfully updated the project to Wagtail 5.1.1